# Show that $\{cos(cx) | c \in \Bbb{R}, c > 0\}$ is a linearly independent subset of $W$.

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, vector-spaces

Let $W$ be the vector space of all continuous real valued functions on $\Bbb{R}$. Let $\mathcal{C}$ = $\{cos(cx) | c \in \Bbb{R}, c > 0\}$. Let $V = Span_\Bbb{R}(\mathcal{C})$. Show that $\mathcal{C}$ is a linearly independent subset of $W$ and hence dim$_\Bbb{R}V = |\Bbb{R}|$.

I can't think of any trig identity that would help prove that $cos(cx)$ is linearly independent. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Linear independence is not a property of a single vector (in this case function, $\cos(cx)$, but a property of a *set* of vectors (in this case $\{\cos(cx)\mid c\in\Bbb{R},\ c>0\}$. Look up the definition, and write it out for this particular problem to see how far that gets you.

Comment: I definitely know where this question came from, heh. How'd you do on the test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $c_1,\dots c_k$ are different positive reals such that
$$
\sum_{k=1}^na_k\cos(c_kx)=0\quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Evaluating at $x=0$ we get $\sum_{k=1}^na_k=0$. Derivate twice and evaluate again at $x=0$ to get $\sum_{k=1}^nc_k^2\,a_k=0$. Repeat the procedure and get a linear system of $n$ equations with $n$ variables:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^nc_k^{2j}\,a_k=0,\quad 0\le j<n.
$$
This is a Vandermonde system, and has a unique solution: $a_k=0$, $1\le k\le n$.

Answer (score 0):

To get you started: you need to show that, if $c_1, \ldots, c_n$ is any **finite** number of pairwise different positive numbers, then the relation
$$\sum_i^n \lambda_i \cos(c_i x) = 0 $$
(valid for every $x$) implies that $\lambda_i=0$ for each $i\in \{1, \ldots, n\}$